# Merge more than 2 layers in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have 3 balls in the scene and need each of them to be lighted from his own light. I managed to separate things in 3 layers. But when I try to merge all 3 layers in Compositor, they are half-transparent. Any hints?

Thank you for your kind attention.

[image: Compositor merge]

Blender file on the link
[Blender file](https://we.tl/t-HqhSwDe7PK)

Comment: Any hints for what? What do you want to do? "Merge" is a very vague term. It does not communicate your goals at all. There is no single way to combine or merge images. There are many ways. You need to specify what you want to do in order for your question to be possible to answer.

Comment: I want each ball to receive light from only its own light source, so that no other lights in the scene interact with it. After my research I found that it is possible through separating objects and lights into different layers. Now I have problems with merging these layers into one picture. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: What about shadows on the ground? What should happen to them?

Comment: I need them from all the balls (and their lights). The plain and the camera are outside of any collections. I’m happy with how each layer looks like, but don’t know how to merge them in one picture and if it’s possible.

Comment: What happens if one of the balls casts a shadow from its light onto another ball? Also should the background be illuminated by all lights? I think you should edit the question and include all of this information in it.

Comment: maybe you can do it with shadow catcher? You'll need to use Alpha Over, not Mix. But if you use Cycles there's now an experimental Light Linking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAwNMCZRP-A

Comment: @moonboots That's it!! Thank you, that is what I'm looking for.